# Liability for selling electronics on eBay

Tags: business, liability, jurisdiction

Say I want to sell my computer on eBay. I'll make a profit and report the profit to state/IRS. No problem there.

What happens if the buyer makes a claim that it fried his cat or any personal injury / property damage claim? Am I personally liable in that they could sue and I could lose my car, etc.? Or is there a limit to potential liability?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a computer that you built/made then yes you could be liable. You need insurance.

If this is a computer that you resold as part of a business undertaking then yes you could be liable - in general, you would have a claim on your supplier. You need insurance.

If this is the sale of second-hand goods in a private not for business way then you would generally not be liable.

Comment: This would be private, not for business. I would only be putting software on the computer, not modifying the hardware. How would the latter affect my potential liability? Thank you!